# Can we calculate dipole moment about infinity?

Tags: electrostatics, dipole-moment

If $Q_{net}$ is zero:

1. can we calculate dipole moment about infinity?
2. if yes, is the dipole moment the same as about origin dipole moment is calculated?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the total charge $Q$ is zero, the dipole moment $\mathbf{P}$ is independent of the point around which you're calculating it. This is because, for any two points $\mathbf{x}_1$ and $\mathbf{x}_2$,
\begin{align}
\mathbf{P}_1 &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} d^3\mathbf{x}~(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_1)\rho(\mathbf{x})\\[5pt]
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} d^3\mathbf{x}~\mathbf{x}\rho(\mathbf{x}) -\mathbf{x}_1 \underbrace{\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} d^3\mathbf{x}~\rho(\mathbf{x})}_{Q= 0}\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} d^3\mathbf{x}~\mathbf{x}\rho(\mathbf{x}) \\[5pt]
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} d^3\mathbf{x}~\mathbf{x}\rho(\mathbf{x}) -\mathbf{x}_2 \underbrace{\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} d^3\mathbf{x}~\rho(\mathbf{x})}_{Q= 0}\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} d^3\mathbf{x}~(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_2)\rho(\mathbf{x})\\[5pt]
&= \mathbf{P}_2.
\end{align}